# What is the difference between hosts and hosts.deny?

Tags: networking, hosts

The question might seem trivial but for the last 36 months I have lived in the illusion that what I put in the hosts.deny file will stop my computer from visiting those sits. But some sites have still been coming through and establishing connections.

But last week I threw in my whole hosts.deny list into the hosts file and now everything that I wanted to block is blocked.

Why have a hosts.deny if having it in the hosts file does the trick?

What I mean by blocking is

127.0.0.1 somesite.topdomain

I asked a similar question a year or so ago, but by then I had not tried putting everything in the hosts-file and no one seemed to connect the dots.

Answer (score 3):

They're used by different tools. See `man hosts;man tcpd`.

`/etc/hosts.deny` is part of the TCP Wrappers package `tcpd` (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrapper)), and acts as an intermediary between an `inetd`-like daemon, and the target TCP service, and is used as an access control mechanism for Incoming TCP connections.

`/etc/hosts` is part of how your system looks up URIs and translates hostnames to IP addresses, and is used for Outgoing TCP/IP requests.

Comment: Thank you. That made it clear. Perhaps that information should be a comment at the beginning of the hosts.deny file or hosts file.