# hosts file and iframes - a strange case

Tags: networking, xubuntu, firefox, hosts

I have a couple of sites blocked in the hosts file. But having created some html-files locally using iframes I found that those sites could be reached through those pages even though my hosts-file have them blocked.

What can be going on?

To explain.
In the hosts file I redirect 127.0.0.1 site.now and 127.0.0.1 www.site.now

In a local file `iframe.html` there is

```
<iframe src="https://www.site.now/" name="iframe" width="500"     marginwidth="10" height="500" marginheight="10" scrolling="auto">
</iframe>
```

and through this iframe i can reach site.now but not if I open that site directly in the browser. What makes the web browser ignore the hosts file when directed through an iframe, while using the hosts file when using address field directly?

Is the error with the OS (xubuntu) or with the web browser (firefox) - where in the code?

In an earlier question I got a clarification between the hosts file and the host.deny which is not the question here.

[What is the difference between hosts and hosts.deny?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800750/what-is-the-difference-between-hosts-and-hosts-deny)

Comment: If anyone can repeat this on their own computer, at least we know that my computer is not alone. Poor old computer. Block a site in your hosts file and put the same site in an iframe-tag.